# Can this aggregate be broken down into smaller aggregates?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

A contract has a list of locations and a list of claims

Business Rule: Every claim needs a location from the contract but there can be only one claim per location. Also, location can be added/removed/renamed in the contract as long they are not being used in a claim.

```
class Contract {
   Guid ContractId;
   List<Location> Locations;
   List<Claim> Claims;
}

class Location {
   Location Location;
}

class Claim {
   Guid ClaimId;
   Location Location;
}
```

**Can the Claim be an aggregate on its own in this context?**

My team is trying to split this into micro services, ie. Contract Service, Claim Service. But because of eventual consistency I can't see how this could ever work! Concurrent users might edit different claims at the same time and select same location or add/remove/rename locations in the contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DDD, Aggregates are consistency boundaries. So an aggregate will be consistent all the time. In other words an business invariants around one single aggregate will be consistent always (before and after any transaction).

Business invariants that are around multiple aggregates will not be also consistent all the time. They will eventually become consistent.

> Can the Claim be an aggregate on its own in this context?

You can have a claim as an aggregate. There is nothing stopping you from doing that. The question is does it benefit to have claim as an aggregate. The bigger question is should ClaimService be a separate context.

You have rules that span across services. This make it difficult to implement these business rules. Unless the complexity of Claim, Location and Contract is big, I wouldn't make it as separate bounded contexts.

Comment: Kimarappan Thanks for the reply ! I'm still not sure how the Claim can be an aggregate on its own, because in order to validate itself it needs to know about all the other claims from that contract and to know about the locations in the contract. From my point of view, the contract is the aggregate root and only the aggregate root can guaranty correctness across the aggregate.

Comment: I would go with the design you have suggested in the comment if the complexity of Claim, Location and Contract is not too much.

Comment: "Business invariants that are around multiple aggregates will not be also consistent all the time. They will eventually become consistent." Are you saying that eventual consistency means "eventually correct"? even if that's the case, I don't see how in this case the aggregate will get back into a valid state. Imaging 2 users, both trying to save 2 claims against same location. Potentially both edits might succeed, because the validation would be based on stale data (eventual consistency).

Comment: Yes eventual consistent means eventually becoming consistent

Comment: When the user saves the claim against the location we can inform the user saying the request is "accepted" and later process business rules across services and then move the state of the request to "confirmed". This will increase the complexity. Do you want to buy the increased complexity is the question